# Compile error with assert(f<char, int>())

Tags: c++

```
#include <cassert>

template<class A, class B>
bool f()
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    assert(f<char, int>());
}
```

Gives compile error: `error: macro "assert" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1`

What is causing the error and is there any workaround?

Live code:

http://ideone.com/4XbGVI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add extra parenthesis:

```
assert((f<char, int>()));
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/NRqgvC)

Comment: Also explain, why your solution works and not the one by OP.

Comment: This works because the grammar for preprocessing tokens includes `()` but also that `,` is a separator between macro arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
int main()
{
    bool tmp = f<char, int>();
    assert(tmp == true);// or assert(tmp);
}
```

Comment: That will work, but I'd prefer a solution which wouldn't call the function when asserts are disabled.

Comment: @NeilKirk: You may still surround code with `#ifndef NDEBUG`.